# when do we say two events are equal

Tags: probability

If the probability of two events are equal, can we conclude that the events are equal? In other words how does one show that the event of getting at most 3 x's is the same as the sum of the events of getting exactly 3 x's and at most 2 x's.

Comment: What you wrote after *In other words* is not related to what you wrote before it.

Comment: "the sum of the events of" - Are you trying to *add* events? Do you mean union of these events? Or, do you mean that the probabilities are to be added?

Comment: "If the probability of two events are equal, can we conclude that the events are equal?" - No. The events of a dice throw being a $1$ and a dice throw being a $2$ are not equal, even though the probabilities are (usually) the same.

Comment: Events are **sets**.  From equal probability you can't conclude equality of events. From equality of events you certainly can conclude equal probability. The event of at most $3$ $x$'s is the disjoint union of the events exactly $3$ and at most $2$.  You get at most $3$ Aces if you get exactly $3$ or at most $2$.

Comment: "If the probability of two events are equal, can we conclude that the events are equal?" - No. To give you a really simple analogy, remember that you cannot say that two sets are equal just because their cardinalities (sizes) match (e.g., $\{1,2\} \neq \{3,4\}$). Similarly, just because two events happen to have the same probability, they are not necessarily the same.

Comment: @all: Thanks. I knew about showing that one is a subset of the other and vice versa approach. I was hoping that there was another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO, same probability is not used to define "equality" of events.  Instead, just say "equal probability", or be fancy and say "equiprobable".